# AntiVirus for AWS Linux 2 EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, linux-networking, sysadmin

Is there antivirus software recommended to install AWS Linux 2 system?what would you recommend we install for that?

In my infra, I'm using the following AWS services:: EC2 (Seoul, Ohio, and Virginia), Load Balancers, Target Groups, SecurityHub, Guard Duty, Lambda, Jenkins, RDS,k S3 , SES, Route53, CloudWatch, CloudTrail, ElasticSearch, CloudFront, DynamoDb, SNS, VPC, ACL, WAF, IAM.

I think Sometimes the packages we install and the application we set up and their dependencies may have security and vulnerability issues. The security and vulnerability issues can either be in a file or the packages we install and can be injected through the websites. To overcome such a scenario we need it in our system

Can anyone suggest to me which antivirus is best for my requirement? also, is there any documentation available on how to install the AV on AWS Linux 2 system?

Comment: This is mostly opinion based, so will probably get closed. However, you probably only need AV on Linux if you're interacting with a Windows domain, such as running a mail server etc. Linux viruses aren't really the same as Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of discussion on whether AV solutions make sense on Linux or not, which I'm not going to get into. AV solutions for Linux do exist and if you want to install any, you can evaluate the existing solutions and choose the option that suits your requirements the best.
I'm not aware of an official recommendation of AWS towards any specific product and I doubt they would publish one.

So in short the answer to your question is: no, there is no clear recommendation on which product to use. You will find some AMIs that are based on Amazon Linux 2 that have security / antivirus software built in already. You could take a look at those if you plan to deploy new servers...